# Node.js/Express post route failing

Tags: node.js, express

Trying out Node.js for the first time. My POST route is failing with "Cannot POST /admin/add-product.html". GET request is being served fine from the same route.  I have had a look around here. Several answers to similar issues but nothing is helping. Here is my code:

./index.js

```
const path = require('path');

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

const adminRoutes = require('./src/routes/admin');
const shopRoutes = require('./src/routes/shop');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use('/admin', adminRoutes);
app.use(shopRoutes);

app.listen(3000);`
```

./src/routes/admin.js

```
const path = require('path');

const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

// served on /admin/add-product GET route
router.get('/add-product', (req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'views', 'add-product.html'));
});

// served on /admin/add-product POST route
router.post('/add-product', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.redirect('/');
  // res.send('<h1>product saved</h1>');
});

module.exports = router;
```

./src/views/add-product.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Add Product</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/">Shop</a></li>
          <li><a href="add-product">Add Product</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
      <form action="/admin/add-product.html" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="title" /><button type="submit">
          Add Product
        </button>
      </form>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Can you try `<form action="/admin/add-product" method="POST">` ?

Comment: To add to the comment, your POST route does not have `.html`, so you have to remove the `.html` from your form's action attribute.

Comment: Thanks Đăng Khoa Đinh. It fixed it! :)

I am happy to mark it as a correct answer if you post it as an answer.

Comment: @ImranAli glad to be of help, I added my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action in the form need to match the route declare in the NodeJS application, it should be :

```
<form action="/admin/add-product" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the .HTML from the action attribute of the form.